# its possible in Angular 4/5 autoinstace a service provider?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I have some services declared like

```
// app.module
@NgModule({
    providers: [
        AuthorsService
    ],
    bootstrap: [
        AppComponent
    ]
})

// authors.service
@Injectable()
export class AuthorsService {
    public constructor() {
        console.log('service constructor');
    }
}
```

Can I do something on service for run `console.log` when is added to provices array like previous code?

When service start I need do some stuff... I like to avoid code like this for service instance:

```
public constructor(
    protected authorsService: AuthorsService
) {

}
// only with that console.log is runned
```

(Please, don't ask why, this is a simple example [for a better use on a library](https://github.com/reyesoft/ngx-jsonapi))

Answer (score 0):

In order to be instantiated, a provider should be injected. Most times it's solved by injecting it into root component, `AppComponent`.

It can also be injected into module constructor or `APP_INITIALIZER` multi-provider, but this depends on how a provider and its own dependencies work. Some of this options may cause circular dependency or race conditions.

Comment: Thans for you reply (example about `APP_INITIALIZER`: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9047#issuecomment-224075188). but I need also on side of service :/. I dont find any solution, your solution can be the best.

Comment: If the service doesn't have dependencies and is initialized synchronously (as the question shows), it could be injected into module constructor as well.